# Numpy matrix multiplication returns nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vector

I have two 2-D matrices, and I want to multiply these two matrices to get a new matrix. The first matrix A has dimension 943 x 1682, and it is shown below:

```
[[ 5.  3.  4. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 5.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  5.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

And another matrix B has dimension 1682 x 20, and shown below:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          3.        ]
 [ 0.          0.57735027  0.57735027 ...,  0.          0.          3.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          1.        ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          2.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

However, when I try A.dot(B), or np.matmul(A,B), I got a new matrix whose values are all nan, as shown below:

```
[[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
..., 
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]
```

I figure this might be a result of multiplying 0. But why would it return nan at every position? And how should I deal with this so that I can get numbers instead of nan?

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: it might help if you tried to reduce the matrices to the smallest possible version that reproduces the problem (then you are likely have found the solution as well...). are there `nan`s in the part that is not printed?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist These are unfortunately the reduced matrices. I think I found some `nan` s. So would it work after I convert all `nan` s to `0`?

Comment: i can't guarantee that this would give the correct/desired result, but the `nan`s should be gone then.
and with reduced i meant: try to find the smallest matrices (they do not need to have any meaning) that reproduce your problem (i.e. that result in `nan`s under the dot product).

Answer (score 3):

A single `nan` column in the first matrix, and\or a single `nan` row in the second matrix, could cause this issue. A way to verify that indeed all values are valid in both matrices is to filter out the `nan`s and see if the shape remains the same:

```
a_shape_before = A.shape
a_shape_after = A[numpy.logical_not(numpy.is_nan(A))].shape
assert a_shape_before == a_shape_after
```

And likewise for B.

Comment: Thank you. a_shape_after returns (31920,), does this mean that there are some nan in the matrix since 31920 < 1682 *20?

Comment: Yup. A single `nan` column in A can cause this issue. use `numpy.argwhere(numpy.isnan(A))` to find the indices of the `nan`s in your matrix.